# Zend Studio 9 include built in Zend Framework Library

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, zend-studio

I recently installed Zend Studio 9 and created a Zend Framework project. In the setup options it says that it includes the Zend Framework library and when a project is created, under all the project files in the php explorer it says it's being included.

While this is true, I notice that the 'library' folder is empty. When I try to run public/index.php in the browser, it doesn't display anything.

My question is how can you include the built in library so that my public/index.php file shows in the browser? I know you can download the zend library files and put them in the library folder, but that gives a ton of warnings, and I can't help but think there is an easier way when the library is supposedly built right in.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Zend Studio, but does Zend Server run your testing environment? (probably installed with the IDE?) - I remember that Zend Server has the Zend Framework preinstalled, what basically means that the library files are installed in some folder that is added to the default include path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding ZF support to a project in Zend Studio makes the IDE aware of the classes and file structure of the library so you get code completion, method descriptions, and argument lists presented to you in the IDE but does not actually give you access to the library.

You will need to download the actual files when you want to run/deploy your project.  You can put them in your library folder, but typically I put them in a more common location that I add to the PHP include path in `php.ini`.  This is optional though.  If you drop the `Zend` folder in your `library` folder, you technically wouldn't need to add ZF support to the project since the builder will become aware of all the ZF content by analyzing all of thy ose files.

On another note, try editing `php.ini` and setting `display_errors` to 1 so you don't get a blank page.  There is an error but it is being hidden due to the display_errors setting.

Comment: Ok cool. I thought I might have been doing something wrong because I get a ton of warnings when I download the library and include it in the project on my own. I get the one error also, but it doesn't give me a blank page. I guess as long as the project runs it's all good. Is there a way to get rid of all the warnings or is that normal?

Comment: What types of warnings are you getting?